# Record square video

Tags: java, android

I use [CameraView](https://github.com/natario1/CameraView) library. It's cool library. It has height and width customizations.

I tried to change them. But unfortunately these settings are only for `CameraView` View, not for video. that is, when recording `CameraView` is square, and in preview video back to rectangular.

I tried to set the parameter in `activity_main.xml` `app:cameraPictureSizeAspectRatio="1:1"`, but the result is the same

**Question**: Tell me how I can solve this problem, how to record video square as in instagram?

Comment: That's not possible, in that there is no requirement for every Android device to support a 1:1 aspect ratio when recording videos. Device manufacturers can do what they want; I do not recall many offering 1:1.
Record a regular video, then crop it (e.g., via ffmpeg).

-